# C# p/invoke to RegisterHotKey for the key combo ALT+TAB not working (returns 0)

Tags: c#, pinvoke, wndproc, registerhotkey

I'm using the following code to intercept the ALT+TAB key sequence in my c# application.

Some relevant snippets:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
```

and

```
bool ret = RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, MOD_ALT, 0x09);
Console.WriteLine("return value:" + ret);
Console.WriteLine("lasterror=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

and

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generic hotkey interception");
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ALT+TAB intercepted");
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Pretty much in the second snippet, ret is false, but when I replace MOD_ALT (which is 0x01) with MOD_SHIFT (0x04), ret becomes true and the hotkey interception works.

I was wondering why this is the case, because the many examples I've seen on the web state that they work.

Comment: AFAIK the combination you want to intercept is a system-wide hotkey - I would expect this to not work in current Windows versions since it would a huge security problem if it did...

Comment: It is an essential Windows shortcut, similar to Ctrl+Esc.  A process isn't allowed to be this disruptive.

Comment: @Hans I think you are mistaken. MSDN: "Before Windows XP, attempting to register AltTab as a hot key would fail. As of Windows XP, not only can you successfully register AltTab as a hotkey, Windows XP will also allow you to handle this event yourself, rather than initiate its own built-in AltTab hotkey handler."

Comment: My experience is that you can register Alt+Tab as a hotkey under Windows XP but not under Windows 7. It's very frustrating that they no longer allow this, since it makes it much harder to write a custom Alt+Tab switcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running as an administrator fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can't pass `0` for the Id param? See the link below, which specifies IDH_ALTTAB, IDH_NEXT, or IDH_PREV. What that corresponds to… I don't know.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997649.aspx#xpvisualstyles_topic3

Comment: I think those constants (e.g. IDH_ALTTAB) are placeholders for user-defined constants that are not shown in the example. It's quite possible that 0 is not a valid id, though.